# Rewrite rule for JBoss7.0

Tags: google

Users currently connect to the app on URLs such as:

```
http://myServer01/crr/
http://example.com/crr/
```

We'd like to simplify this to:

```
http://myServer01/
http://example.com/
```

with out my app name
can some one help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

[The docs](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/rewrite.html) appear to suggest a mod_rewrite (Apache) syntax is used:

> The rewrite valve implements URL rewrite functionnality in a way that is very similar to mod_rewrite from Apache HTTP Server.
>
> The rewrite valve can be configured as a valve added in a virtual-host. See virtual-server documentation for informations how to configure it.
>
> It can also be in the `jboss-web.xml` of a webapp configured as a normal value:
>
> ```
> <valve>
>     <class-name>org.jboss.web.rewrite.RewriteValve"</class-name>
> </valve>
> ```
>
> The valve will then use a `rewrite.properties` file containing the rewrite directives, it must be placed in the `WEB-INF` folder of the web application

So, in `rewrite.properties` you would have something like this (assuming "crr" is your app name):

```
RewriteRule !^/?crr/ /crr%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

If it's like Apache then you would also need a `RewriteEngine On` directive preceding this, however, I see no mention of this in the docs.

Reference:

- [JBoss 7.0 - The Rewrite Valve](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/rewrite.html)

---

> Instead of changing Jboss-web.xml and adding property file, Is there any chance that i can do changes in standalone.xml ???

Yes, depending on JBoss version it does appear to be possible to put everything in `standalone.xml` instead, with a change of syntax.

Try the following, inside the `<virtual-server>` container:

```
<rewrite pattern="!^/crr/(.*)" substitution="/crr/$1" flags="L"/>
```

Reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20042452/jboss-as-7-1-server-level-redirect
- https://developer.jboss.org/thread/232562

Comment: Instead of changing Jboss-web.xml  and adding property file,  Is there any chance that i can do changes in standalone.xml  ???

Comment: Yes, that does appear to be possible. I've updated my answer.